# "Foreach + if" only works for the last element

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

**Context:**

I have a form with checkbox and a php page to process the data. I check my data: everything is ok.

To manage the checkbox I do a "FOREACH" in which several "IF" loops with instructions and sql queries are located, according to the boxes checked in the form.

I try to loop on my array to enter the loop "IF" adapted for each of the boxes checked by the user.

**Issue:**

When I run the script, I check 3 or 5 boxes, only the last loop "IF" is taken into account ... :(

I checked on the side form HTML and PHP test POST: everything is ok.

**So my question is:**

Where did I mess up so that the foreach would only pass the last element of the array in the "IF" loops?

**Here's the code:**

```
if ( isset($_POST['ModalMultipleColorEdit']) && !empty($_POST['Planning_ID2']) && !empty($_POST['CaseColor2']) && !empty($_POST['CaseWeek2']) )
{  
    //------- Extract Needed Posted Data
    $TargetID = $_POST['Planning_ID2'];
    $TargetColor = $_POST['CaseColor2'];
    $TargetMonth = $_POST['CaseMonth2'];


   //----- GET OLD DATA
   $REQ = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM `Planning` WHERE `ID_Planning` =  ".$TargetID." ;")
   or die(var_dump($REQ->errorInfo()));
   $DATA = $REQ->fetch();



   // Explore Targeted Weeks Array
   foreach( $_POST['CaseWeek2'] as $CheckedWeek )
   {
        //----------- IF TARGET MONTH IS JANUARY   
       if ( $TargetMonth == "Janvier"  && $CheckedWeek == "(S-1)" )
       {           
              //------- Extract Color String Period
              $GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);

              //------- Change Period Color
              $GetColor[0] = $TargetColor;

              //------- Build New Color String
              $NewCaseMonth = $GetColor[0].".".$GetColor[1].".".$GetColor[2].".".$GetColor[3].".".$GetColor[4];

             // ------ UPDATE REQUEST
             $REQ2 = $DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');                        
             $REQ2->execute(array($NewCaseMonth, $TargetID)) or die(var_dump($REQ2->errorInfo()));
             $REQ2 = NULL;        
       }


       if ( $TargetMonth == "Janvier"  && $CheckedWeek == "(S-2)" )
       {      
             //------- Extract Color String Period
             $GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);

             //------- Change Period Color
             $GetColor[1] = $TargetColor;

            //------- Build New Color String
            $NewCaseMonth = $GetColor[0].".".$GetColor[1].".".$GetColor[2].".".$GetColor[3].".".$GetColor[4];

            // ------ UPDATE REQUEST
            $REQ2 = $DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');
            $REQ2->execute(array($NewCaseMonth, $TargetID)) or die(var_dump($REQ2->errorInfo()));
            $REQ2 = NULL;     
        }


       if ( $TargetMonth == "Janvier"  && $CheckedWeek == "(S-3)" )
       {          
            //------- Extract Color String Period
            $GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);

            //------- Change Period Color
            $GetColor[2] = $TargetColor;

            //------- Build New Color String
            $NewCaseMonth = $GetColor[0].".".$GetColor[1].".".$GetColor[2].".".$GetColor[3].".".$GetColor[4];


            // ------ UPDATE REQUEST
            $REQ2 = $DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');

            $REQ2->execute(array($NewCaseMonth, $TargetID)) or die(var_dump($REQ2->errorInfo()));
            $REQ2 = NULL; 
       }


       if ( $TargetMonth == "Janvier"  && $CheckedWeek == "(S-4)" )
       {      
            //------- Extract Color String Period
            $GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);

            //------- Change Period Color
            $GetColor[3] = $TargetColor;

            //------- Build New Color String
            $NewCaseMonth = $GetColor[0].".".$GetColor[1].".".$GetColor[2].".".$GetColor[3].".".$GetColor[4];

            // ------ UPDATE REQUEST
            $REQ2 = $DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');                     
            $REQ2->execute(array($NewCaseMonth, $TargetID)) or die(var_dump($REQ2->errorInfo()));
            $REQ2 = NULL;     
       }


       if ( $TargetMonth == "Janvier"  && $CheckedWeek == "(S-5)" )
       {
             //------- Extract Color String Period
            $GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);

            //------- Change Period Color
            $GetColor[4] = $TargetColor;

            //------- Build New Color String
            $NewCaseMonth = $GetColor[0].".".$GetColor[1].".".$GetColor[2].".".$GetColor[3].".".$GetColor[4];

            // ------ UPDATE REQUEST
            $REQ2 = $DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');                         
            $REQ2->execute(array($NewCaseMonth, $TargetID)) or die(var_dump($REQ2->errorInfo()));
            $REQ2 = NULL; 
       }
   }


   //------- REDIRECT WHEN SUCCESS AND NO MORE TARGETS
   header('Location: PlanningNow.php?Process=Success');
   exit();

}




else
{
   header('Location: PlanningNow.php?Process=ErrorForm');
   exit();
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help ! :)

Comment: looks like issue in your logic. You are getting last element updated because every time in loop your previous value will be updated with latest value so at last you will get last updated value

Comment: That is what I thought... But I can't figure out how to solve it ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Whats an auto-incremented array?

Comment: That is just called an indexed array

Comment: Yes what i need to do is execute the queries on each iteration... Do you think i need to create an auto-incremented array or an indexed array ?

Comment: The data I wish to  preserve as an array are the ones contained in "$_POST['CaseWeek2']". I mean data from the checkbox

Comment: here's what it holds :  Array
(
    [CaseTitle2] => Test Karim
    [CaseMonth2] => Janvier
    [CaseWeek2] => Array
        (
            [0] => (S-1)
            [1] => (S-2)
            [2] => (S-3)
        )

    [CaseColor2] => #0D6500
    [Planning_ID2] => 1
    [ModalMultipleColorEdit] => 
)   //Data remain  unchanged

Comment: Everything looks good with that.  So by your method, you would be calling 3 separate updates, right?  This can be consolidated into one.

Comment: Really ? How could I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to make up some data for testing.  Consider this approach to reduce query calls to one, and largely consolidate your code...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2c289ce327aeba6c8d66ad79ec95054aed0ba4e))

```
$_POST['CaseWeek2']=['(S-2)','(S-3)','(S-5)']; // target checkboxes
$_POST['CaseColor2']='purple';  // target color
$_POST['CaseMonth2']='Janvier'; // target month

$checkedWeeks=['(S-1)','(S-2)','(S-3)','(S-4)','(S-5)'];  // possible checkboxes

$DATA['Planning_M1']='red.orange.yellow.green.blue';  // old data from db
$oldcolors=explode('.',$DATA['Planning_M1']);

if($_POST['CaseMonth2']=='Janvier'){
    // var_export(array_intersect($checkedWeeks,$_POST['CaseWeek2']));
    $keys=array_keys(array_intersect($checkedWeeks,$_POST['CaseWeek2'])); // get appropriate keys
    // var_export($keys);
    $values=array_fill(0,sizeof($keys),$_POST['CaseColor2']);  // generate equal number of values
    // var_export($values);
    $replacements=array_combine($keys,$values);  // combine keys and values to make correct array
    // var_export($replacements);
    $newcolors=array_replace($oldcolors,$replacements);  // replace old values with new values
    var_export($newcolors);
    //$REQ2=$DB->prepare('UPDATE `Planning` SET Planning_M1 = ? WHERE `ID_Planning` = ?');                        
    //$REQ2->execute(array(implode('.',$newcolors), $TargetID));    
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'red',
  1 => 'purple',
  2 => 'purple',
  3 => 'green',
  4 => 'purple',
)
```

---

Oh and for the record, the reason your earlier iterations were being "ignored" was because of:

```
$GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);
```

Each time you called an UPDATE, you were effectively pulling the old cached `$DATA['Planning_M1']` data, swapping in a single color, and overwriting the earlier iteration's UPDATE.

---

---

If you wanted to keep your code mostly the same, you could write:

```
$GetColor = explode("." , $DATA['Planning_M1']);
```

**before the `foreach()` loop**, then conditionally modify `$GetColor` as you are currently doing with `$GetColor[n]`.  Then after the loop finishes, you can make a single UPDATE call to the database using the fully modified `$GetColor` data.

Comment: Oh yes ! You were right, now i understand better, and it worked like charm ! Thank you so much ! ;)